# Routing to action inherited from base controller on play

Tags: inheritance, playframework

I am working on an app using Java in Play 1.2.4.  I have controller B extending controller A. Does this mean that controller B inherits the actions from A?  If so, how do I route to those without routing directly to controller A?

Example:

```
public class ControllerA {
    private static void action{
        //I want to run this
    }
}


public class ControllerB extends ControllerA {

}
```

can I call action like this: `ControllerB.action`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible/easy to do in play 1, but in play 2.x you can use a DI framework like google guice. This will let you create  singleton controllers without static methods so inheritance will work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

IT does if I remember well. However it is better practice to use the @With annotation rather than extend your controllers.

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    @Before
    static void preAction() {
       Logger.info("Request: [%s]", request);
    }

    public static void login() {
       render();
    }
}


@With(Application.class)
public class Bookings extends Controller {
...
}
```